# How do you politely ask permission to deviate from received instructions?

Tags: nuances, politeness, keigo, business-japanese, email

After I agreed to proofread a professor's 論文, he instructed me to print out a hard copy and write edits on it in red, *as well as* send him the Word document back with my edits done on the original file. Rather than write edits by hand on a hard copy *plus* edit the document file, I'd rather turn on Track Changes in Word and send him back 1) the edited document file with Track Changes on so he can cleanly see where I changed anything, and 2) a duplicate "clean" copy of the edited file (Track Changes off).

He wrote by email:

> 作業の段取りですが、
>   （１）お送りした原稿を「プリントアウト」して、赤字で修正する。
>   （修正を書き込みにくければ、文章の設定を変えてもかまいません。
>   例えば、1頁20行にする、など）
>   （２）修正した文章をデジタルデータにする。
>   （デジタルデータには、どこを修正したか、書き込む必要はありません）
>
> つまり、赤い字でチェックをした紙の原稿と、
>   修正を終えたデジタルデータの両方をいただきたいのです。

Is the following a polite response requesting to use Track Changes in Word instead of write by hand, or how can I make it more polite? Is there any part of this that sounds rude and needs to be removed or replaced? Is there any set phrase often used in the situation of asking permission to deviate from received instructions that should be included?

> ◯◯先生
>
> ご連絡ありがとうございます。
>
> 失礼ですが、一つ提案がございます。原稿をプリントアウトして、ペンで紙に赤字で修正することの代わりに、ワード（Microsoft Word）の「変更履歴」（Track Changes, トラックチェンジ）機能を使うことを許可されることのご配慮をよろしくお願いいたします。文字の挿入や削除、書式の変更、コメントが、色つきの文字や右余白の吹き出しできれいに表わされています。お世話になっております。
>
> ◯◯先生が知っているとは思うんですが、念のために「変更履歴」の仕方：
>
> http://allabout.co.jp/gm/gc/297925/
>
> http://ascii.jp/elem/000/000/204/204722/
>
> ◯◯先生にご迷惑をかけない場合、本件について格別のご配慮をよろしくお願いいたします。この特異な状況をご理解いただくよう、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few weird bits, here's how I would write:

> チェックした原稿の件ですが、原稿をプリントアウトして、ペンで紙に赤字で修正する代わりに、ワードの「変更履歴」機能を使うというのはいかがでしょうか。文字の挿入や削除、書式の変更、コメントなどが、色つきの文字や吹き出しできれいにでます。
>
> 念のため、「変更履歴」の使い方は次の通りです：
>
> http://allabout.co.jp/gm/gc/297925/
>
> http://ascii.jp/elem/000/000/204/204722/
>
> こちらの方法でしたら、チェック原稿と修正文書の間に齟齬がない形で仕上げられると思います。何卒ご検討のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

That said, 変更履歴 is pretty hard to use, if he wants an old school print out, I'd be very weary to ask him to use it. If I were you I'd offer to print out the changes out (you can do that). That way it's pretty close to what he wanted!

Comment: Thank you very much, your suggestions are extremely helpful! I will offer to print out the changes.